# EDGE não consegue copiar imagens grandes usando JS de/para um canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Tenho o seguinte código, que copia pedaços da imagem "smoothchartshowAnalisysCopy" (500px X 250px)  para a imagem maior (32172px X 250px).

```
var c   = document.getElementById('analysisFullGraph1'); 32172px X 250px
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

var imageNow = document.querySelector('#smoothchartshowAnalisysCopy');
var ctxImageNow = imageNow.getContext('2d');


function copy(){
    var elmnt  = document.querySelector('#analysisFullGraphContainer1');
    var x = elmnt.scrollLeft;
    var y = elmnt.scrollTop;
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(x, 0, 828, 270);
    ctxImageNow.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);

}
```

Está funcionando perfeitamente com IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari e Vivaldi, exceto com o *MS Edge*. O *MS Edge* só copia os pedaços da imagem do começo até a posição de *14000px*.

Em posições maiores de *14000px*, não aparece nem sequer um erro, mas nada é copiado.

Não encontrei nada na documentação da Microsoft, nem algo relevante no Google.

Comment: Você tem certeza que olhou o log do console? Talvez seja algum limite do navegador. Eu não recomendaria fazer um canvas largo assim, dá para fazer ele encaixar na página facilmente. Qual é sua intenção de criar um canvas gigante? Isso pode causar uma perda significante de performance na página.

Comment: O `ImageData` do canvas reserva 4 informações para cada pixel. Pense bem! : 32172x250 = 8043000x4 = 32172000, sua `ImageData().data` no canvas iria conter 32172000 elementos que reservam informações de pixels. Você pode muito bem fazer um mecanismo.